# Generate large .csv file (1 Million rows+) within .NET Framework web application

Tags: asp.net, azure, performance, csv, openxml-sdk

We have a .NET Framework (4.8) web application deployed in Azure and it has a feature where the user can export raw data to a .csv file. Dataset is large and could be millions of rows with around 20 columns.

Previously, the export feature used OpenXML SDK to generate a .xslx file but that process was way too long (could take up to 2 hours). Also, usually users click on export and then they close the browser and some times the app domain would get recycled by the application pool lifecycle and that leads to the fact that the file generation would never finish as the process gets killed.

We changed the file format to .csv and now the process takes around 15 minutes for a million rows. Reducing the execution time = reducing the chance that the app domain gets recycled before file generation ends.

BUT, we are still never sure that the file will always be generated and we are scared that in the future (as DB is constantly growing) the process will get killed easily again.

We're currently thinking about another approach, i've been investigating in Azure Web Jobs, Windows service, etc. but I did not find anything that would cover our needs : generate a large file at user request from web interface and then send download link by email. The process needs to be fast and we need to be sure that it will always finish execution.

I was wondering if any of you would have any ideas on how to solve that.

We are wondering on how to extract that file generation from the web application and how to trigger that at user request (meaning that we would need to pass parameters to that file generation).

Thanks!

Comment: So the problem is actually that the "app domain gets recycled"? I mean it seems like you have a fine solution. But you now have to find a new solution because of the "recycling"... what's up with that? App needs to run, right? Delegating the backup task to an external device could else still fail for the same reason. Why might it "get recycled"? Rather solve that.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. But I dont think we can solve that as it is related to the application lifecycle, there is no way to prevent the application pool from recycling the app domain. I am looking for a solution to "extract" that file generation process from the web application.

Comment: Seems like you already found the solution: Azure web job or Windows service, an Azure Function etc. You should pick an approach and try to implement it. If you get stuck on a specific part of the implementation, then that would make for a much better question here on Stack Overflow: at that point you'd provide us with a [mcve] and clearly explain what you're trying to accomplish and what's not working about your implementation.